# How to count every char except of word?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to count length of string without spaces and 
 tags.
My JS pattern doesnt work because it also not counts 'b' and 'r' chars.
My code is here:

```
content.match(/[^\s^<br />]/g).length
```

How to fix it?

Comment: You could do a .replace instead of .match - `content.replace("<br />", "").length`.  Also why is this being downvoted so much?  It has a clear attempt and code to replicate the problem, not all of us are js regex kings

Comment: _All_ HTML tags, or just `br`?

Comment: What your regular expression does: https://regexper.com/#%2F%5B%5E%5Cs%5E%3Cbr%20%2F%3E%5D%2Fg

Comment: Should *length of string* also include symbols? Or are you looking for only word-related characters (`a-zA-Z0-9_-`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a match, just use `.replace()`. Match always returns an array, and because primitives in Javascript are immutable, you can make a new string without those characters easily using replace().

`let newString = oldString.replace(/\s/g, '') //replace all whitespace with empty spaces`

`newString = newString.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/g, '') //replace <br> and <br /> with empty spaces`

and then just do `newString.length`

In the future, try using https://regexr.com to test your regex matching

Comment: `<br>?\s?\/?>?` should really be `<br\s*\/?>`

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to remove all the HTML tags (not just `<br/>`), you could add your string as the HTML to a new element, grab the `textContent`, and then run a regex match on that.

```
let str = '<div>Hallo this is a string.</div><br/>';
let el = document.createElement('div');
el.innerHTML = str;
let txt = el.textContent;
let count = txt.match(/[^\s]/g).join('').length; // 19
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/yLusgof7/)**